# Constant buffer receives wrong value

Tags: c++, hlsl, fragment-shader, packing

<strike>I have got this HLSL struct and when I pass in a Material buffer from C++ to HLSL, some values in my struct is wrong. I know this because I have tried for example setting the emissive color to Vector4(0, 1, 0, 1) or GREEN and in my pixel shader I return only the emissive color and the result becomes BLUE!
And when I set the emissive to (1, 0, 0, 1) or RED, the pixel shader outputs GREEN color. So it seems like everything is shifted 8 bytes to the right. What might be the reason behind this?</strike>

EDIT: I noticed that my virtual destructor made my structure bigger than usual. I removed that and then it worked!

HLSL struct

```
struct Material
{
    float4 emissive;
    float4 ambient;
    float4 diffuse;
    float4 specular;
    float specularPower;
    bool useTexture;
    float2 padding;
};
```

C++ struct

```
class Material
{
    virtual ~Material(); // - I removed this!
    helium::Vector4 m_emissive;
    helium::Vector4 m_ambient;
    helium::Vector4 m_diffuse;
    helium::Vector4 m_specular;
    float m_specularPower;
    int m_useTexture;
    float m_padding[2];
};
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think you can have a struct and class with the same name.

Comment: I should clarify that the first struct is HLSL :)